# Web3js works in my localhost NODE server but return an error in my remote webserver

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ethereumjs

All Web3js functions works correctly in my NODE (10.7.0) localhost server but the same configuration return the next error in my remote NODE webserver (same configuration and versions).

Any idea? Thnks

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/nodejs/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:43:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/nodejs/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:95:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/nodejs/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/nodejs/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (/home/nodejs/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:349:14)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/nodejs/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:252:61)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:382:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: It appears the script can't connect to the remote server. Is it behind a firewall or a NAT? Can you try using curl/wget to send RPC commands?

Comment: Yes, my Centos server has ConfigServer Security & Firewall but I dont known if its blocking it because no errors in the "web3.providers.HttpProvider" or  "web3.eth.Contract" declarations.

How can I send curl/wget  RPC commands? Thank you!

Comment: I can make "https.get" request to the EtherScan API without problems and if I disabled the server firewall all works.

Any idea how the ConfigServer firewall are blocking web3js? Thank you!

Comment: You can use [`eth_blockNumber`](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_blocknumber) to test connectivity.

Comment: The problem is the CPanel ConfigServer Security & Firewall. Its blocking Web3.js.
If I disconnected all works.
I dont know how to avoid CSF block Web3. Thank you for the clue Ismael.

Comment: I haven't used that firewall, so I can't help you there. Ethereum uses port 8545 for http and 8546 for websocket so maybe opening those port might help.

Comment: I solved opening the TCP OUT 30303 (Ethereum listeners) and 8545 (JSON-RPC) ports.